# Query on Last Array Value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
db.chat.find().pretty().limit(3)
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593921425ccc8150f35e7662"),
    "user1" : 1,
    "user2" : 2,
    "messages" : [
        {
            "capty" : 'A',
            "body" : "hiii 0"
        },
        {
            "capty" : 'B',
            "body" : "hiii 1"
        },
        {
            "capty" : 'A',
            "body" : "hiii 2"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593921425ccc8150f35e7663"),
    "user1" : 1,
    "user2" : 3,
    "messages" : [
        {
            "capty" : 'A',
            "body" : "hiii 0"
        },
        {
            "capty" : 'A',
            "body" : "hiii 1"
        },
        {
            "capty" : 'B',
            "body" : "hiii 23"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593921425ccc8150f35e7664"),
    "user1" : 1,
    "user2" : 4,
    "messages" : [
        {
            "capty" : 'A',
            "body" : "hiii 0"
        },
        {
            "capty" : 'B',
            "body" : "hiii 1"
        },
        {
            "capty" : 'B',
            "body" : "hiii 24"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am not to figure out the query that will give me list of user2 and the body where user1=1 and last capty of messages = 'B'. i.e output should be last 2 rows.

i.e desireable output.

```
user2:3, "body" : "hiii 23"
user2:4, "body" : "hiii 24"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing here is the aggregation [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) to get the last element from the array,

```
db.chat.aggregate([
 { "$match": { "user1": 1,  "messages.capty": "B" } },
 { "$redact": {
   "$cond": {
     "if": { 
       "$eq": [ { "$slice": [ "$messages.capty", -1 ] }, ["B"] ]  
     },
     "then": "$$KEEP",
     "else": "$$PRUNE"
   }
 }},
 { "$project": {
   "user2": 1,
   "body": {
     "$arrayElemAt": [
       { "$map": {
         "input": { 
           "$filter": {
             "input": { "$slice": [ "$messages",-1 ] },
             "as": "m",
             "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$m.capty", "B" ] }
           }
         },
         "as": "m",
         "in": "$$m.body"
       }},
       0
     ]
   }
 }}
])
```

I'm actually being "extra safe" in the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage with the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) but it all basically the same.

First the query selects the documents, we cannot actually say at this point to "only" match the last element of the array but we want to filter documents that do not have the condition on the array at all.

The [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) is the actual thing that looks at the "last" array entry and tests the value of the field. We can notate just the field from the array by `$messages.capty` which returns just an array of those items. Here we then [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) or even [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) if you want to get the last value, being the index of `-1`.

At this point we only "filtered" the "documents" which do not match the condition. The final [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage takes the last element of the array, checks it matches the condition ( which it should by the earlier stages ), extracts the value of `"body"` and turns the single array content into just the plain value.

You can alternately forego the "carefulness" and simply just grab the last array element since `$redact` should have done it's job:

```
db.chat.aggregate([
 { "$match": { "user1": 1,  "messages.capty": "B" } },
 { "$redact": {
   "$cond": {
     "if": { 
       "$eq": [ { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$messages.capty", -1 ] }, "B" ]  
     },
     "then": "$$KEEP",
     "else": "$$PRUNE"
   }
 }},
 { "$project": {
   "user2": 1,
   "body": {
     "$arrayElemAt": [ "$messages.body", -1 ]
   }
 }}
])
```

The whole thing really breaks down to "match the *possible* documents with a query" and then "compare and extract the last element with [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) or [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/)".

Results are:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("593921425ccc8150f35e7663"),
        "user2" : 3,
        "body" : "hiii 23"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("593921425ccc8150f35e7664"),
        "user2" : 4,
        "body" : "hiii 24"
}
```

Comment: nice explaination, please correct the syntax error :-)

Comment: @QuizMaster Already did. Sorry laptop had a meltdown and it took me a few minutes.

Comment: Thanx  friend:-)